# _config.yml is not recognized while building jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

Here are the exact steps as requested:

- I downloaded `Ruby`.
- Installed `Jekyll` and `Bundler`
- Checked if they were properly installed by `Jekyll -v` and `Bundler -v`
- I have the version `Jekyll 3.8.4` and bundler version is `Bundler 1.16.6`
- Jekyll new Healthcare Transition Toolkit (That's where i get the new site)
- Then i did `Jekyll build` and `Jekyll serve` and i get the error:

`Configuration file: none`

Comment: what do you mean "clean up the gem" ?  Please update your question and list exact steps you took to produce this error. Not "followed instructions on website" but the actually things you did.

Comment: Here i updated the post as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a step, but also dont use spaces in your project name and no need for upper case on commands or path names

```
# this command will create a new project in a new relative folder
jekyll new healthcare-transition-toolkit

# then you need to cd into that folder
cd healthcare-transition-toolkit
```

At this point your commands should work fine

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

or

```
bundle exec jekyll build
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!! This is working. Just 2 more questions: 1) What does ```cd``` stands for and how can i make GitHub my relative directory in this case? I can post a separate issue for it, if you recommend?

Comment: Thanks i did get rid of the space. My mentor has been mentioning this right from the beginning.

Comment: if you don't know that `cd` is universal command for `change directory` then wow you really have a LOT to learn. This is basic OS directory commands 101.

Comment: So basically this is going to be the extension of my root directory since GitHub is one folder down from the existing location of the website folder.

Comment: I don't know what your directory structure it. But `jekyll new` will create a new jekyll project under your current directory but in a new sub directory with the name you give it, which is why you should not use spaces, otherwise you'll have to escape the spaces. But you really need a basic lesson like https://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/utilities-how-to/how-to-use-terminal-the-basics/ or google for something for windows if that's your OS

Comment: Thanks for posting the tutorial. I don't have spaces in my site name any longer.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Helped me figure out the absolute to relative path access on local machine administrator. Also, by the way, this is not the only job i have. :)